# PHP - If div has certain class then

Tags: php, if-statement

My question is simple.

I have the following code:

```
    <div class="last" 
    <?php 
    if hasClass(last){
      echo " style='width:100%;' ";
    } 
    ?> 
    ></div>
```

I know the `if` statement is wrong, but the idea is there. I want to know how can I check if this `div` has the `.last` class then `echo` something.

I've been searching around but didn't work anything (didn't find much though).

Best regards.

Comment: You can do it very easy with jQuery if you're ok with that I'll answer your question.

Comment: It can't be done with php that easy, almost sound impossible to me. You can archive this using ajax

Comment: @Hudixt ajax isn't necessary

Comment: @Daan I was saying its one way of doing these type of things

Comment: @Hudixt neither is it impossible. There are several DOM parsers out there, and PHP also ships with DOMDocument.

Comment: It can be done using PHP  but you need to parse the DOM to do it - not trivial by any means and almost certainly not worth it for what you're trying to do. It's probably worth re-thinking what you're trying to achieve. If you're set on this you need something like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

Comment: @thpl For that the html should be contained in a string

Answer (score 1):

As already in the comments told it's possible with PHP with DOM parsers.

I'm gonna give you 2 very simple solutions which will save you a lot of work:

CSS:

```
<style>
.last {
  width:100%;
}
</style>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('div').hasClass('last')){
      $('div').css('width', '100%');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on server, so it generates HTML. If you have that class="last" you don't need to check - it's part of the code....hard-coded.

But you can have some PHP variable and depending on it's place print out class and also style for that other element:

```
<?php 
$print_last = true;
?>

...

   <div <?php if ($print_last) echo 'class="last" ';
    <?php 
    if ($print_last){
      echo " style='width:100%;' ";
    } 
    ?> 
    ></div>
```

But if you want to check on html element you have to do it on client side (browser) from JavaScript and jQuery can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check that using PHP, however that couldn't be done easliy (you'll need to parse buffered HTML using DOM parser, then look up for divs, etc...).... Much better solution is to do that with Javascript/jQuery, using `Document.getElementsByClassName()` function.

Sample solution:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("last"); 
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
 var element = elements[i];
 element.style.width = "100%";
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

@azhpo 
Obviously the HTML being the front end language you have to pass the elements either through some submit button or via ajax request.

1. Using submit button: select the class name of div using either javascript

   var className = document.getElementById("myDIV").className
   document.getElementById("myHiddenField").value = className;

   Now on clicking the submit button it would get submitted
2. Using ajax:
   Again take the classname either through javascript / jquery 
   var className = jQuery("#myDiv").attr("class");
   Now fire ajax query and send the class name to your script

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'file.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'class='+className,
      success: function(data){//do whatever you want},
      error:function(){//do whatever you want}
   });
   ```